# Prove that $K(u) = ||u||Mu+f$ is a contraction

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, contraction-operator

Let $M$ be a $2 \times 2$ real matrix such that $$\parallel{}Mx\parallel{} \leq \frac{1}{4}\parallel{}x\parallel{}$$

for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ where $\parallel{}\parallel{}$ is the euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I want to show that $$K(u):=||u||Mu+f \;,\;\;\;\text{     } ||f||\leq \frac{3}{4}$$ is a contraction on the closed unit disc $B_1(0)$.
Can someone give me a hint since I have no idea how to get further than the last inequality:
\begin{align}
||K(u)-K(v)|| &= \left|\left|M||u||u-M||v||v\right|\right|\\
&= \left|\left|M(||u||u-||v||v)\right|\right|\\
&\leq \frac{1}{4}||(||u||u-||v||v)||
\end{align}

Comment: $\|u\|u - \|v\|v = \|u\|u - \|u\|v + \|u\|v - \|v\|v$.

Comment: Thank you! How could I not see it myself